# How to print fetched JSON data in loop on Android Textview

Tags: php, android, json, textview

I got stuck here where I want to print value in Android using Textview. But I am getting only last line.
Here response is JSON encoded array name which I am parsing and all declared string is attribute of obtained data which is to be printed in 4 textview using Linear Layout. I am taking data from database using PHP.

```
  TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ID);
  TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Name);
  TextView textView3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Department);
  TextView textView4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Semester);

  jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("response");
        String ID, Name, Department, Semester;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < jsonArray.length()) {
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            ID = jsonObject1.getString("ID");
            textView1.setText(ID);
            Name = jsonObject1.getString("Name");
            textView2.setText(Name);
            Department = jsonObject1.getString("Department");
            textView3.setText(Department);
            Semester = jsonObject1.getString("Semester");
            textView4.setText(Semester);
            i++;
        }
```

I have five row (tuple) of data and I want to print every row in new line. So, there should be 4 attribute value in all five line. Is there any way to do this without storing data.

Edit : I have to print 4 attribute for having all 5 tuple(row). Means I need total of (4 X 5 =) 20 textview.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are overriding the content of your `textviews` with each iteration.

You should try to append it to the present text, e.g.:

`textview.setText(textview.getText() + "some string")`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried PDO fetchAll method. This method mainly gets all the rows from a database according to query in array format.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have 4x5 = 20 textviews.

If you approve that, you must use listview or recyclerview to achive this.

[Here is an example of how to use Listview](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are looping your jsonArray on textviews. In each iteration your textView is getting a value and in every new iteration the previous value of your textView is getting changed by new value of jsonArray for the next ith index. You can either create list of textViews or create a recycler view so that every new jsonArray values is inserted and printed.

[Refer to this link to learn about ListViews](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

You only have a 4 TextView here, yet you want to print 5 people. If you want them to be appended into these 4 textView in the format of:

ID:          1 2 3 ...

Name:        John Mike Person3 ...

Department:  Math CS Eng ..

Semester:    1 2 3 ..

you do:

```
jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("response");
String ID, Name, Department, Semester;
int i = 0;
while (i < jsonArray.length()) {
     JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
     ID = jsonObject1.getString("ID");
     textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() + " "+ ID);
     Name = jsonObject1.getString("Name");
     textView2.setText(textView2.getText().toString() + " "+ Name);
     Department = jsonObject1.getString("Department");
     textView3.setText(textView3.getText().toString() + " "+ Department);
     Semester = jsonObject1.getString("Semester");
     textView4.setText(textView4.getText().toString() + " "+ Semester);
     i++;
}
```

The key is to get the existing text:

```
 TextView textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.abbreviated);
 String newText = jsonObject1.getString("Your_Field")
 String oldText = textview1.getText().toString();
 textview1.setText(oldText+ " " +newText);
```

But if you want a list that shows each person individually, I recommend using **[RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)** :

1. Create a file called list_item.xml in res/layout:

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/department"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/semester"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

2. Create Adapter as MyAdapter.java in your package:

   public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
       private Arraylist people;

   ```
   // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
   // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
   // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
   public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
       // each data item is just a string in this case
       public TextView tv_id;
       public TextView tv_name;
       public TextView tv_department;
       public TextView tv_semester;

       public ViewHolder(View view) {
           super(v);
           textView1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id);
           textView2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
           textView3 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.department);
           textView4 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.semester);
       }
   }

   // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
   public MyAdapter(Arraylist myPeople) {
       people = myPeople;
   }

   // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
   @Override
   public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
       View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
           .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

       return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
   }

   // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Person person = people.get(position);
        holder.id.setText(person.getID());
        holder.name.setText(person.getName());
        holder.department.setText(movie.getDepartment());
        holder.semester.setText(movie.getSemester());

   }

   // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
   @Override
   public int getItemCount() {
       return people.length;
   }
   ```

   }
3. set recycler view in MainActivity.java

   ```
   mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

   // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
   // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
   mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

   // use a linear layout manager
   mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
   mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

   Arraylist<Person> people = new Arraylist<>();

   //Store your json object into this arraylist of persons
   //Create a Person Object

   // specify an adapter (see also next example)
   mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);
   mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
   ```
4. Add this segment to activity_main.xml layout

```html
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

5. Have Fun!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for being so generous. I searched for this problem and found a solution using TableLayout which looked better and easier to me. Here is code I am giving which I used.

My XML code is :

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/hscrll1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView">
        </TableLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

and my JAVA code is where I created TableRow, Textview filled its data and added it.

```
TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);
jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("response");
String ID, Name, Department, Semester;
int i = 0;
while (i < jsonArray.length()) {
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            ID = jsonObject1.getString("ID");
            Name = jsonObject1.getString("Name");
            Department = jsonObject1.getString("Department");
            Semester = jsonObject1.getString("Semester");
            i++;

            TableRow tableRow1 = new TableRow(this);
            TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
            tv1.setText(ID);
            tv1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            tv1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tv1.setTextSize(20.0f);
            tableRow1.addView(tv1);

            TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
            tv2.setText(Name);
            tv2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tv2.setTextSize(20.0f);
            tableRow1.addView(tv2);

            TextView tv3 = new TextView(this);
            tv3.setText(Department);
            tv3.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tv3.setTextSize(20.0f);
            tableRow1.addView(tv3);

            TextView tv4 = new TextView(this);
            tv4.setText(Semester);
            tv4.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv4.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tv4.setTextSize(20.0f);
            tableRow1.addView(tv4);
            tableLayout.addView(tableRow1);
}
```